# Network failover

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, failover

I have an infrastructure with 2 links to communicate with my server, there are 2 cables, connected in eth0 (main) and eth1 ( backup - there is connected to a 4g router).
I want eth0 to be used whenever possible, but when it is down, I will change to the eth1 connection.
And when I'm using the eth1, I will test in the background if the eth0 is working again, if yes, I will come back to use the eth1.

My script uses the "route" to change between the interfaces.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
//test main interface
if ping -c $N_PING -I $LAN0 $IP_TEST &>/dev/null ; then
    //connecting to main interface (remove backup routes)
    route del -net $BKP_HOST netmask $BKP_MASK $LAN1
    route del -net default gw $BKP_GW $LAN1
else 
//test backup interface
    if ping -c $N_PING -I $LAN1 $IP_TEST &>/dev/null ; then
        //connecting to backup interface (put backup route as default)
        ip route flush table main
        route add -net $HOST netmask $MASK $LAN0
        route add -net default gw $GW $LAN0
        route add -net $BKP_HOST netmask $BKP_MASK $LAN1
        route add -net default gw $BKP_GW $LAN1
        ...
    fi
fi
```

my main objective is to minimize the effects of the transaction for the system, as this code will execute periodically, whenever the main network is communicating it will use this one again.

Is this a good way? or is there a better way?

thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged debian? We do not support that... our sister site does https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm running this in a Debian SO, and use his commands.

Comment: Debian is not Ubuntu and answers for Ubuntu are not always useable on Debian. That's why questions related to debian need to go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ (is it a subsite for Linux, AskUbuntu is specifically for ubuntu (hosted by stackexchange but in relation with Canonical).

Comment: For example, https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic is written for Ubuntu. I do not care, will not support, its use on not-Ubuntu systems.